# Compass compilation fails when trying to import images support

Tags: ruby, css, sass, compass-sass

I am trying to compile my scss file but forever reason it fails bigtime.

My SCSS:

```
@import "compass/css3/images";

@import "_fonts.scss", "_colors.scss", "_mixins.scss", "_variables.scss";

body {
    background-color: $color-background-site;
}

/*------- HEADERBOX -------*/
#headerBox {
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 49% 46%, $color-gradient-header-light, $color-gradient-header-dark);
}
```

It fails with

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - C:/Development/Projects/SparNord.LeadGenUmbraco/SparNord.LeadGenUmbraco/development/studiepakken/.sass-cache/75fcaf1b4852ceb732871195e41567cc2a7d8997/C%058/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/stylesheets/compass/_support.scssc20160630-9812-149m318


Backtrace:
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tempfile.rb:133:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tempfile.rb:133:in `open'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tempfile.rb:133:in `block in initialize'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tmpdir.rb:130:in `create'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tempfile.rb:131:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/util.rb:1228:in `new'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/util.rb:1228:in `atomic_create_and_write_file'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/cache_stores/filesystem.rb:39:in `_store'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/cache_stores/base.rb:51:in `store'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/cache_stores/chain.rb:19:in `block in store'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/cache_stores/chain.rb:19:in `each'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/cache_stores/chain.rb:19:in `store'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/engine.rb:417:in `_to_tree'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/engine.rb:312:in `to_tree'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:326:in `block in visit_import'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:88:in `block in with_import'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:88:in `with_import'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:325:in `visit_import'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `block in visit'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `visit'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:328:in `block (2 levels) in visit_import'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:328:in `map'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:328:in `block in visit_import'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:88:in `block in with_import'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:88:in `with_import'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:325:in `visit_import'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `block in visit'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `visit'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:328:in `block (2 levels) in visit_import'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:328:in `map'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:328:in `block in visit_import'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:88:in `block in with_import'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:88:in `with_import'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:325:in `visit_import'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `block in visit'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `visit'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `block in visit_children'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `map'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `visit_children'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:169:in `block in visit_children'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:181:in `with_environment'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:168:in `visit_children'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `block in visit'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:188:in `visit_root'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:159:in `visit'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:8:in `visit'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:36:in `css_tree'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/engine.rb:281:in `render'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-import-once-1.0.5/lib/compass/import-once/engine.rb:17:in `block in render'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-import-once-1.0.5/lib/compass/import-once/engine.rb:29:in `with_import_scope'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-import-once-1.0.5/lib/compass/import-once/engine.rb:16:in `render'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:494:in `update_stylesheet'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:215:in `block in update_stylesheets'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:209:in `each'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:209:in `update_stylesheets'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/sass_compiler.rb:40:in `compile!'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/commands/update_project.rb:49:in `perform'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/commands/base.rb:18:in `execute'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:19:in `execute'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:43:in `perform!'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:15:in `run!'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/bin/compass:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/bin/compass:44:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/compass:22:in `load'
C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/compass:22:in `<main>'
```

If I remove

> @import "compass/css3/images";

it will compile perfectly fine, but then my radial-gradient will not be "CSS'd"

My config.rb

```
require 'compass/import-once/activate'

# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "stylesheets"
css_path = "C:/Development/Projects/SparNord.LeadGenUmbraco/SparNord.LeadGenUmbraco/css/studiepakke/"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "javascripts"
```

What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a reinstall of the 32bit version. That did the trick